# What is the etymology of <*> from Applicative in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, notation, applicative, nomenclature

Where did the name `<*>` first begin to appear in literature or code, and did it come with any explanation for the choice of symbol?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's an ASCIIification of the notation used in the original idioms paper: "[Idioms: applicative programming with effects](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf)".  That notation, was in turn, inspired by an already ASCIIified version from Sweirstra's and Duponcheel's paper on error-correcting parser combinators: "[Deterministic, Error-Correcting
Combinator Parsers](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier101/Papers/1996/DetErrCorrComPars.pdf)".  That came from "[Functional Parsers](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~fokke101/article/parsers/)" by Jeroen Fokker.  This paper does not indicate where it came from which may mean it originated it.  I would not be surprised if it was used for parsing before then.

Comment: Just to help in finding this notation in the Fokker paper: it’s introduced on p.5, at the start of §4.

Answer (score 14):

[The original idioms paper](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf) already uses `⊛` for application; `<*>` was picked as an ASCII-art approximation of that, since `(*)` isn't available (it is the syntax of the prefix form of the infix operator `*`).